# How to use Image instead of border-right with CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css

I want to use image to place a border to the right side of my menu item. Currently I am doing this by a css code as follow:

```
.menu-item{
border-right:2px solid #f1f1f1;
}
```

But its height is bit more than what I was looking. So some people out there suggested me to use image instead of this.

So how to use that here?

Comment: Can you show a bit more code and what exactly is your current and wanted outcome?

Comment: http://africancorporatefinance.com/ see this...I just want those menu separators smaller in height.

Comment: it depend's on the height of the <li> so decrease the height and give proper padding it will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use images as background something like this:

```
.menu-item {
    padding-right: 2px;
    background: url('/path/to/image.png') no-repeat center right;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yxyyw/